# Unsupported operand type(s) for x: 'int' and 'str"

Tags: python-2.7

I am currently trying to make a python script on my raspberry pi to allow myself to watch twitch streams though a string in the url. I have tried many methods to add the string to the url but all seem to come up with the same result. 
"TypeError: unsupported operand types(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'"

Bare in mind that I am very new to python coding.

```
import os

print 'You have entered Stream, this program uses twitch.com to stream'

stream = raw_input('Twitch stream you would like to watch. http://www.twitch/')

os.system("livestreamer http://twitch.tv/'%s' medium -np 'omxplayer -o hdmi'") % (stream)
```

Thanks in advance
~ iSlendy

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses look misplaced.

Try this:

```
os.system("livestreamer http://twitch.tv/'%s' medium -np 'omxplayer -o hdmi'" % (stream))
```

What was happening is that the `os.system` call was returning an `int`, and then you were using the `%` operand between that `int` and the `str` within the `stream` variable.  If your intent is for the `stream` variable to be an integer, you need to cast it as such because the input coming from `raw_input` is always a string.